How to add inset border on image in Elementor?
enter image description hereI’m using an Image Widget inside a Container in Elementor, and I want to add an inset border with 24px of padding around border. I don't want to use the image as a background; I want to use the image widget itself.
What I want to achieve:
An inset border should be placed inside the image (with the padding) so that the image slightly sticks out from under the border on all sides.
I attempted to use a ::before pseudo-element to create the inset border. The idea was to position the border inside the image with 24px of space around it. I tried using top, left, right, and bottom properties to create the padding, but the border still ends up extending outside of the container, especially on the right and bottom sides.
I experimented with adding a box-shadow effect to simulate the inset border, but this didn't give me the true inset border effect. The shadow created a blurred effect around the image, but it didn't provide a solid, defined border that I could control with padding.

Please show us the code you have tried. Without seeing this any answer is just a guess.

In Html Structure Use an Image Widget inside a container, as you already have.
In CSS Apply styles to the Image Widget and the ::before pseudo-element to achieve the desired effect.

i did this on the image widget and it works: selector:before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
border-radius: 12px;
border: 2px solid #B88849;
inset: 24px;
}
